# uitableview didselectrowatindex works only for first tableview not with second tableview in same viewcontroller?

Tags: uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Two tableviews is showing in `viewcontroller` but when I select cell from second tableview app crashes. Please help me. Here is my delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (atableView == self.tableView) {
NSLog(@"selected %@ row", [[[marrXMLData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]);
NSString *link = [[[marrXMLData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"link%@",link);
stringNotifyLink = [NSString stringWithString:link];
if (stringNotifyLink!=NULL) {
    NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myweb.co.in/portal/%@",stringNotifyLink];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.WebViewHome loadRequest:requestObj];
    tableView.alpha = 0;
    [tableView reloadData];
} else {
    tableView.alpha = 1;
    [tableView reloadData];
}

}else{

    NSLog(@"ssssssssss");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self viewDidLoad];
    });

}}
```

Comment: You should not call viewDidLoad, it is supposed to be called by the system

Comment: @valfer okay.But anyway its not entering the else block.not even nslog is showing.what should I do?

Comment: error showing is  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x3f80000c) and the class AppDelegate definition line is highlighted.

Comment: I run your code without problems (after removing viewDidLoad). How did you set the delegate/datasource of your two tables? Can you provide a complete code example showing the bug?

Comment: @valfer I use storyboard for adding delegate/datasource for both tables. But the problem is that in debug area its not showing an error,but anyway my app is crashing. I searched everywhere couldnt find the any good solution.Right now I am using one spinner view and one tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an exception breakpoint in XCode to stop the app at the crash line (see figure)

[image]